# Why won't Unity 2017.3.0f3 recognise Ontrigger2D /OnCollision2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers, collision

I have a 2d box collider on a "Magnet" sprite and a circle collider on a "Ball" sprite. On the Magnet sprite, I turned on "Is Trigger" and tried a few rigidbody settings: Kinematic, Static and Dynamic. The Ball also has a Dynamic rigidbody on it. I'm using Unity 2017.3.0f3.

For the time being I just want to check if an object has entered the Magnets collider and log the object's name.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Magnetism : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log(other.name);
    }

}
```

I also tried using the OnCollisionEnter(Collision other) and it still doesn't do anything. Oddly I have no errors as well. Oh, also in one forum, I found someone mention that using a onCollisionEnter/onTriggerEnter. That didn't work for me either.

Comment: Looks like it's working now for some reason. Though all I did was restart and place the script on again. Perhaps it's an odd bug with Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got two objects (magnet with box2D and ball with circle). The magnet object has a script attached that does the same as you. Everything works as it should. (Tested with your version.)

Just try to double check everything and otherwise, try to create a new project and see if it occurs. If that doesn't work, test with 2017.3.1f1. If all that does not work, with I highly doubt, send a bug report to Unity and they'll help you.

Comment: I did all the things you guys mentioned so i guess ill try it in another project and see if i have the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the checklist to make sure your collision works

1. Make sure the layers your gameObjects are in are set to collider under Project Settings -> Layer Collision Matrix.
2. Make sure at least one of the colliding bodies have a Rigidbody2D (not rigidbody, must be 2D) attached to it
3. Both of the objects must have a Collider2D
4. Make sure the Magnet's collider has IsTrigger set to true
5. The script in which the IsTriggerEnter2D function is present must be on the same object which has the collider2D (Also make sure this collider is set as a trigger)
6. Make sure the size of the colliders isn't 0 or is big enough. This can happen if you create a 2D sprite first and put the actual sprite image later
7. Make sure all of the components and gameObjects are enabled/active

I know some of them are trivial but still easy to miss

**Edit: One more thing; the rigidbody2D must have simulated set to true.**

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that all colliders and rigidbodies you're using are `2D`.

In order for the `OnTriggerEnter2D` to work, at least one of the colliders must have the `Is Trigger` active.

To make a quick test, you can disable all rigidbodies and check with only the colliders active.

The script code is perfectly fine and should work.

Comment: I've done all of that. Still doesn't work for some reason. I don't get errors either so it is very odd. I decided to check if there was something wrong with the colliders by turning off the trigger and the objects collide with each other as you'd expect.